# Why can't I store data from fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store in a variable ('randomColor') a random color from fetched colors, so that I can use it in my application. Whenever I log it in the console, it shows it is undefined.
Logging the color directly from the fetch:

```
.then(color => console.log(color))
```

has been successful, since the console shows a random color.

I also tried fetching all the colors and getting a random color from them, but the same issue.

```
var randomColor;

globals = {
    currentColor: randomColor
};
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(obj => Object.keys(obj))
    .then(keys => keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)])
    .then(color => randomColor = color);
```

What to do?

Comment: Make sure you only use `randomColor` inside `.then`, or in function that you call from inside a `.then`. I suspect you're trying to use it outside, which means you're using it before it's been assigned a value.

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: Why chain so many `.then`s for simple non-asynchronous methods? The final three `.then` expressions could just be one: `.then(obj => { let keys = Object.keys(obj); let color = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]; randomColor = color; });` That said, I imagine Paulpro is right - it sounds like you're trying to use the color somewhere else.

Comment: @TylerRoper Because I was not on a machine on which it was easy to do when I wrote that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine your code step by step

```
var randomColor;

globals = {
    currentColor: randomColor
};
```

You've created a variable `randomColor` which is currently `undefined` and passed it to a property of `globals` object. So in `globals` you have

```
globals = {
    currentColor: undefined
};
```

After that you make an asynchromous call

```
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(obj => Object.keys(obj))
    .then(keys => keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)])
    .then(color => randomColor = color);
```

All the code is absolutelly correct and after the request is completed you get some random color in your `randomColor` variable. However, as long as **primitives are passed by reference (like objects)** your `globals.currentColor` still remains to be `undefined`.

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(obj => Object.keys(obj))
    .then(keys => keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)])
    .then(color => {
        // Here you can update all the required data
        randomColor = color;
        globals.currentColor = color;
        console.log(randomColor, globals);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the asynchronous nature of the promise you are invoking, it may be the case where you `console.log(randomColor)` the promise is not yet fulfilled and the value of `randomColor` remains undefined. randomColor only becomes the value you want it to become at the end of the promise chain `.then(color => randomColor = color);`. When you fire the promise any following synchronous code will run to completion before your promise is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
const randomColor = null;

await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json')
  .then(res => 
  {
    const keys  = Object.keys(res.json());
    randomColor  = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });

console.log(randomColor);
```

Comment: Only if you're in an `async` function; not at the top level.